# How to manipulate a API endpoint address based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

I am playing around with some HTML and JavaScript with the end goal of creating a simple website that displays the current weather. I haven't used API's before and I have limited knowledge of JavaScript so this might be a very bad question. Can I change the endpoint address based on a user input?

I have written some front-end which displays a simple form.

```
<section id="weather">
            <div id="nav">
                <div id="locate">
                    <div id="container">
                        <form action="index.js">
                            <label for="location">Location:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="location" name="location" required>
                            <input type="submit" value="Let's Go!">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="output">
                    <div id="container">
                        <!-- Output of API -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </section>
```

I was thinking that this could run a JavaScript file that gathers the input of the form HTML file and do something like this:

```
const location = document.getElementById(location)
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&APPID=API
```

I tried programming something to do this but as I have limited knowledge of both javascript and API's I keep failing. Before I was a lot of time on this can someone tell me if this is even possible?
By the way I have set-up an API key but I just haven't shown it.

Thanks,

mrt

Comment: a very lengthy way to do it....

`const locationInput = document.getElementById("location");`

`const locationValue = locationInput.value;`

const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationValue}&APPID=API`

Comment: Thanks Craig for your answer! I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: no problem at all
Gonna post as an answer so that we can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is just a very lengthy way to do it so that you can understand each step

Step 1: First you want to get access to the input element:

`const locationInput = document.getElementById("location");`

Step 2: Then you want to grab the value of that input element

`const locationValue = locationInput.value;`

Step 3: Then you'd want to use that value in the URL

`const url = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationValue}&APPID=API`

---

```js
function fetchAPIData() {
  const locationInput = document.getElementById('location');
  const locationValue = locationInput.value;
  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationValue}&APPID=API`
  // do the URL Request

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', fetchAPIData);
});
```

```html
<section id="weather">
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="locate">
      <div id="container">
        <form action="index.js">
          <label for="location">Location:</label>
          <input type="text" id="location" name="location" required>
          <input type="submit" value="Let's Go!">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output">
      <div id="container">
        <!-- Output of API -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

A much shorter way would be:

```
const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${document.querySelector("#location").value}&APPID=API`;
```

Comment: This doesn't show an onclick event @mrt, shout if you need assistance with that

Comment: Thanks Craig. Just had a quick look about the onlick event, would I run it as a function through the submit button or add it onto end of getElementById()?

Comment: just added the onclick event to the answer :) goodluck!